# What's the cause of This Error and how to fix It?

Tags: elasticsearch

I installed Elasticsearch and Kibana 8.4.1 in VM ubuntu 22.04 ad I give this VM 2G RAM, 50 G disk, and 2 CPU
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device

```
elastic@elqstic:~$ sudo systemctl status elasticsearch.service
[sudo] password for elastic:
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-09-15 11:10:54 UTC; 48min ago
       Docs: https://www.elastic.co
   Main PID: 1459 (java)
      Tasks: 91 (limit: 2196)
     Memory: 1005.3M
        CPU: 4min 46.879s
     CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service
             ├─1459 /usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk/bin/java -Xms4m -Xmx64m -XX:+UseSerialGC -Dcli.name=server -Dcli.script=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Dc>
             ├─1519 /usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk/bin/java -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -Djava.security.manager=allow -XX:>
             └─1540 /usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/x-pack-ml/platform/linux-x86_64/bin/controller

sept. 15 11:11:03 elqstic systemd-entrypoint[1519]:         at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip@8.4.1/org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.DatabaseNodeService.lambda$retrieveD>
sept. 15 11:11:03 elqstic systemd-entrypoint[1519]:         at org.elasticsearch.server@8.4.1/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingR>
sept. 15 11:11:03 elqstic systemd-entrypoint[1519]:         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
sept. 15 11:11:03 elqstic systemd-entrypoint[1519]:         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
sept. 15 11:11:03 elqstic systemd-entrypoint[1519]:         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
sept. 15 11:11:03 elqstic systemd-entrypoint[1519]: Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
sept. 15 11:11:03 elqstic systemd-entrypoint[1519]:         at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
sept. 15 11:11:03 elqstic systemd-entrypoint[1519]:         at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:349)
sept. 15 11:11:03 elqstic systemd-entrypoint[1519]:         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core@8.4.1/org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.writeToDe>
```

Answer (score 0):

> No space left on device

Means that your disk is full. Simply remove some data and your server should be able to restart

Comment: thanks @Val for your response i have other question plz in the doc here of elastalert i need to have python 3.6 because me i have python 3.10 i don't know if work ? https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_elastalert.html#

Comment: But since this question is answered, please ask your new question in a new thread, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73734878/the-version-of-python3-and-elastalert