# the version of python3 and elastalert

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert

I have python3.10 installed in my ubuntu 22.04 and I want to install Elastalert in the doc, it requires python 3.6
I should change the version to 3.6 or not?
https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_elastalert.html#

Answer (score 0):

Yes because not all Elastalert dependencies support 3.10. If it's possible in your case you can use a Docker container to provide an isolated Python 3.6 environment for the app, so you don't have to downgrade the system Python.

Note, that Yelp discontinued Elastalert some time ago so there'll be no upgrades/patches for this but there is a community-maintained successor called [Elastalert2](https://github.com/jertel/elastalert2) that is using Python 3.10, you might want to consider switching.